# Remove gray line in clearfix from <div class="wrap clearfix"> Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-7, border, clearfix

I would like to remove the gray line caused by the clearfix elements in my D7 theme (MD Photo). In particular, the `div class="wrap clearfix"` element, which has an unnecessary gray line at the bottom of the `body` elements.

I have tried quite a few fixes, but they haven't given me any results. Here's the list, so far

```
.clearfix:after {content:' ';}
.wrap: {border: none;}
.clearfix {border:none;}
```

And a host of other, similar border and content remover ideas.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have any live examples demonstrating this gray line?

Comment: add fiddle or html code

Comment: Yep, sorry. www.cb1creative.com

Comment: It's the gray line below at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at Drupal 7, it seems as though this line you are referring to is added by the following:

```
.pager a, .view-latest-from-blog li, .comment, .tabs ul.primary,
.tabs ul.primary li a, .tabs ul.primary li.active a, .tabs ul.primary li a:hover,
.meta-share-wrap, .meta_share, #footer {
    border-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

In your case, it's being applied to the `#footer` element, therefore you would either remove the `#footer` selector from the initial declaration, or you would use the following to overwrite it:

```
#main-content #footer {
    border: none;
}
```